# Which countries issue sanctions against individuals and/or companies involved in significant corruption?

Tags: sanctions, corruption

US Department of State has a list of Corrupt and Undemocratic Actors Report that includes individuals and companies that are sanctioned by the US, namely not allowed to enter in the US:

> Foreign persons listed in this report shall have their visas revoked
> immediately and any other valid visa or entry documentation will be
> cancelled, absent an exception or national security interest waiver.

Similarly, the UK seems to have a similar section, [the UK sanctions relating to global anti-corruption](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/uk-sanctions-relating-to-global-anti-corruption), the [first sanctions being announced in 2021](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-sanctions-22-individuals-involved-in-serious-international-corruption):

> sanctions target 22 individuals involved in notorious corruption cases
> in Russia, South Africa, South Sudan and throughout Latin America

I am wondering if there are other countries that have issued similar sanctions. I found [this OECD document](https://www.oecd.org/mena/competitiveness/39997682.pdf) about the impact of the OECD Anti-Bribery Convention that seems to address a similar issue (my emphasis):

> Impact of the OECD Anti-Bribery Convention: The Convention has changed
> the rules of the game. It has increased the visibility of corruption
> of foreign officials; it has brought bribery to the fore. Today, there
> are more than 150 ongoing foreign bribery investigations.
> **Approximately 40 individuals and companies that committed foreign
> bribery have been penalized**, in some cases with hefty multi-million
> dollar fines.

However, it is not clear if these penalities also include individual country penalties similar to the ones issued by the US and UK (e.g. cancelled visas, not allowed to do business in the country).

Which countries issue sanctions against individuals and/or companies involved in significant corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you already mentioned the US, sanctions are not the only means of fighting corruption at the disposal of the US government.

[Foreign Corrupt Practices Act](https://www.justice.gov/criminal-fraud/foreign-corrupt-practices-act) makes it illegal for any US persons, or entities, to bribe a foreign official.  However, it **also makes it illegal for any officer (anywhere in the world) of a public company listed in the US** to bribe a foreign official.

["Anti-bribery and corruption:global enforcement and legislative developments 2017"](https://www.freshfields.com/globalassets/services-page/global-investigations/publication-pdfs/gi-abc-guide-2017.pdf) is mentioned as a reference for "cooperation in enforcement action between countries" in the areas related to FCPA enforcement in [FCPA's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Corrupt_Practices_Act).

There are 32 other countries listed in the document. It has a summary of various degrees to which those countries have measures to combat foreign corrupt practices, by their citizens, as well as cooperation with foreign law enforcement in combating corrupt practices in their own countries.